# Cambiar Button["text"] antes de que se ejecute un loop con python y tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, opencv, asyncio

Estoy intentando crear un bot para un videojuego. El asunto es que quiero que al presionar el boton <kbd>start</kbd> en la interfaz gráfica el texto del botón cambie a `"stop"` y luego se ejecute una búsqueda de imagen

El problema es que al intentar hacerlo la función que contiene el loop para buscar la imagen se ejecuta antes de que el texto del botón cambie a `"stop"` de forma que simplemente se queda con el texto `"start"` hasta que la imagen sea encontrada y salga del loop.

Así quedó el código tras el último intento de resolver este problema sin resultado alguno:

### interfaz.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from imagesearch import *
from ejecutarPrograma import change


raiz = tk.Tk()

startBoton = tk.Button(text="Start",command=lambda widget='startBoton': change(startBoton),height=3,width=20,state="normal")
startBoton.pack(side="bottom")      


raiz.mainloop()
```

### ejecutarPrograma.py

```
from imagesearch import *
import asyncio
from tkinter import Button
import time

def change(boton):
        asyncio.run(DetectScreenImage(boton))


async def DetectScreenImage(boton):
        Button.config(boton, text="Stop")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        if imagesearch_loop("images\initiateLink.jpg",2) !=-1:
                print("Imagen Detectada")
```

### imagesearch.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import random
import time


 '''
    Searchs for an image on the screen

    input :

    image : path to the image file (see opencv imread for supported types)
    precision : the higher, the lesser tolerant and fewer false positives are found default is 0.8
    im : a PIL image, usefull if you intend to search the same unchanging region for several elements

    returns :
    the top left corner coordinates of the element if found as an array [x,y] or [-1,-1] if not

    '''
    def imagesearch(image, precision=0.8):
        im = pyautogui.screenshot()
        #im.save('testarea.png') usefull for debugging purposes, this will save the captured region as "testarea.png"
        img_rgb = np.array(im)
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        template = cv2.imread(image, 0)
        template.shape[::-1]

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
            if max_val < precision:
                return [-1,-1]
            return max_loc

    '''
    Searchs for an image on screen continuously until it's found.

    input :
    image : path to the image file (see opencv imread for supported types)
    time : Waiting time after failing to find the image 
    precision : the higher, the lesser tolerant and fewer false positives are found default is 0.8

    returns :
    the top left corner coordinates of the element if found as an array [x,y] 

    '''
    def imagesearch_loop(image, timesample, precision=0.8):
        pos = imagesearch(image, precision)
        while pos[0] == -1:
            print(image+" not found, waiting")
            time.sleep(timesample)
            pos = imagesearch(image, precision)
        return pos
```

Comment: Hola Gregori ¿Hay alguna razón por la que intentas usar corrutinas y asycio? Tkinter no está diseñado para trabajar conjuntamente con un ciclo de eventos de asyncio y la integración puede ser complicada, sería mucho más simple usar un hilo (threading). Actualmente bloqueas la interfaz por culpa del `while` de `imagesearch_loop`

Comment: Que tal FJSevilla? la verdad es solo un intento desesperado por hacer que funcionara lo que intento hacer. Soy nuevo programando y más aun con python por lo que usé asyncio en vez de usar un hilo ya que me parecía más sencillo de escribir, pero si me dices que usando un hilo puedo resolver el problema entonces pondré manos a ello!

Comment: Funcionó! Te agradezco mucho la ayuda!